# Should I always call ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical even if GetPrimitiveArrayCritical fails?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to access to a char[] from JNI code, avoiding if possible a copy. For now, here is what I do :

```
void my_function(JNIEnv *env, jcharArray array) {
    jsize len = env->GetArrayLength(array);
    if (env->ExceptionCheck() == JNI_TRUE)
        return;

    jchar *chars = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(array);

    // process chars and len

    env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(array, chars, JNI_ABORT);
}
```

According to [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetPrimitiveArrayCritical), `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` may return `NULL` when an OOM exception was "thrown". However they do not tell explicitly if `ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical` should be still called in that situation.

Should I do

```
jchar *chars = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(array);
if (chars == NULL)
    return;
```

or

```
jchar *chars = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(array);
if (chars != NULL) {
    // process chars
}
env->ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(array, chars, JNI_ABORT);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical(…, NULL, …)` will fail. But I must confess that I never experienced `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical()` to return NULL. It's a pity there is no way to ask for the bytes conditionally, i.e. no JNI function `GetPrimitiveArrayCriticalNoCopyOrFail()`!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of docs is that, there is nothing to release, if you don't get your "chars". By calling release, you don't release your "array", just elements associated with the array. It frees "chars" if necessary (only if it is a copy)

Releasing "array" is necessary if you are the owner of it. In this case:
{code}

```
int len = 10;
jcharArray array = env->NewCharArray(len);
if (!array) return;
jchar* chars = env->GetCharArrayElements(array, NULL);
if (!chars) { env->DeleteLocalRef(array); return; }
{... do something...}
env->ReleaseCharArrayElements(array, chars, JNI_ABORT);
env->DeleteLocalRef(array);
```

Also, I found this sample of production code which explicitly calls to ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical only if the returned pointer is not null.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/libjpeg_turbo/turbojpeg-jni.c&q=GetPrimitiveArrayCritical&sq=package:chromium&l=365

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [openjdk code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l2648), it seems that the call to `ReleasePrimitiveArrayCritical` is necessary to unlock the GC (`GC_locker::unlock_critical`) that was locked in the `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` call.

Seems also that java array and native array arguments are ignored, and that `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` never returns NULL anyway.

This is valid for openjdk 7 only though.